# Angular-Cli package.json commands

Tags: angular, angular-cli, package.json

I'm not sure this question is specific to Angular-cli, and I'm fairly sure I'm doing something a little daft.

I've added the following to the `scripts` area of the `package.json` of my project:

`"prep": "ng build --prod --output-path output --base-href APP-NAME"`

I thought this would allow me to run this command with `npm prep` from the command line / in tasks, but each time I try I get an error that it's not a valid command. Any ideas why this would be?

Comment: Nothing to do with angular. `npm run prep`. Give me a moment to search for the dup on running npm scripts.

Comment: Aw, is that what I missed? D'oh. How come the other scripts in the package.json execute without `run`?

Comment: I think you mean `ng serve` etc. That's `ng` and not `npm`

Comment: Yeah, think I'm mixing myself up. Should've learned the npm cli stuff separate from angular. Thanks! :)